# Setinterval stutters generating a random number sequence

Tags: javascript, performance, setinterval

I'm trying to build a script set generates randomly a number between one and six and just displays the number in the browser. At the beginning there is a possibility to set a value for the interval. I have a code that does exactly what I want. The only problem is that the interval is not smooth. It stutters somehow. 
Has someone an idea how I can improve the code that the random numbers are displayed fluently?

```
<html>
<body>

<p style="font-size: 500; color: red; text-align: center" id="random_number"></p>

<script>

var interval = parseInt(prompt("Intervall [ms]:", ""));

fRandomNumbers(1,6);

window.setInterval(function(){fRandomNumbers(1,6)}, interval);

function fRandomNumbers(min,max)
{
    var random_number = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;             
    document.getElementById("random_number").innerHTML = random_number;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I understand you completely, by "stutter" you mean that the interval doesn't seem exact? Sometimes it waits longer than other times? What interval are you using?

Comment: I tried a jsfiddle. I noticed sometimes it looks like it might stutter but that's because the randomly generated number was the same as it was so it looks like it stalls because of the lack of change.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. Sometimes it takes a bit longer until the next number appears. Somehow a bit irregular. I use 900 ms as an interval.

Comment: Try appending to innerHtml (using += instead of =) and see that it adds a number every time but sometimes it adds the same number. That is probably the stall.

Comment: Yeah, @CoreyOgburn is right. You have a one in six chance of selecting the same number two times in a row and when that happens it *looks* like the number didn't change.

Comment: Here's a simple jsfiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/coreyog/NyYG8/ The red number is all the code you have (maybe sped up a little). The black numbers are a history of the generated numbers. When the red number "stalls" you'll see in black that the number just came up multiple times in a row.

Comment: Well Thanks a lot for your help. I'm really impressed that it worked so fast. :)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn. Thanks a lot for the great visualization. Do you maybe have an idea to the possible improvement I posted beneath the answer from Oriol? That'd be great :)

Comment: @user3124124 Check my comment on his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @CoreyOgburn and @Iwburk pointed, the problem is that sometimes you get the same number:

> You have a one in six chance of selecting the same number two times in
>   a row and when that happens it looks like the number didn't change.

Then, to solve it, just make sure the new random number is different than the previous one:

```
var interval = parseInt(prompt("Intervall [ms]:", "")),
    random_number;

fRandomNumbers(1,6);

window.setInterval(function(){fRandomNumbers(1,6)}, interval);

function rand(min,max,diff) {
    var n;
    while(diff === (n = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min)){}
    return n;
}

function fRandomNumbers(min,max)
{
    random_number = rand(min,max,random_number);             
    document.getElementById("random_number").innerHTML = random_number;
}
```

**Warning 1**: The `rand` function above can produce an infinite loop, e.g. if called like `rand(1,1,1)`

**Warning 2**: Be aware that the resulting sequence of numbers won't be random, because a (large enough) true random sequence would contain some equal adjacent numbers. Then, it doesn't emulate well a dice, as @CoreyOgburn pointed.

Comment: This works really fine. A further improvement for me would be to allow the case that the random numbers are generated in a sequence in general. But then it would be really cool to see that. Is it possible to improve the code that the generated number is just flashed. Than nothing is shown and then the next random number flashes and so on?

Comment: Since you're using 1-6, I imagine this is a dice roll. If that's the case, I wouldn't exclude duplicate rolls (doing so ruins the randomness) instead I would use some jQuery animations to help make it obvious that a roll has happened. Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coreyog/NyYG8/1/) that fades in and out to show a new number.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn in jsfiddle it looks just the way I need it. But when I put it together in my html doc it doesn't work. My Code is:

Comment: `<html>
<body>

<p style="font-size: 500; color: red; text-align: center" id="random_number"></p>

<script>

var interval = parseInt(prompt("Intervall [ms]:", ""));

fRandomNumbers(1,6);

window.setInterval(function(){fRandomNumbers(1,6)}, interval);
var count = 0;
function fRandomNumbers(min,max)
{
    var random_number = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;             
    $('#random_number').fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).html(random_number);
        $(this).fadeIn(100);
    });
}


    
</script>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: I did use the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) that you weren't previously using. You'll need to download and add it to your html. I don't want to rewrite their fadeIn/fadeOut functions. Not to mention they get a lot of other things right.

Comment: Thanks. I could figure it out with your great help. For your information: The tool will be used in a sports club to practice the eye food coordination. Thanks a lot. :)